# Safari - Error sound when pressing arrow keys to navigate gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari

I have an image gallery on my site and I the left and right arrow keys can be used to navigate it. Chrome doesn't make a sound when pressing the left or right arrow key but Safari does. It sounds like an error sound.

I commented out the code that moves to the next/previous image and the sound still occurs. This means that it is not due to my code that there is a sound. I am using jquery to detect keypresses.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
      case 37: // left
        $(".gallery-nav-left").click();
      break;

      case 39: // right
        $(".gallery-nav-right").click();
      break;

      default: return;
  }
});
```

Why does this only happen in Safari?

Comment: try adding `return false;` at the end. It will prevent default browser behavior. The arrows are used to scroll the window, so it's seems that Safari give error sound when there are no scrollbar at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That didn't work. I just tried e.preventDefault() too but still the sound occured.

Comment: I've realized that you're using keyup, try keydown instead of keyup, you can't prevent behavior in keyup because it's called after the native behavior.

Comment: That worked! Can you post that in a separate answer so I can accept it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Safari browser give error with sound when you press arrows, and it's probably because there are no horizontal scrollbar. Native browser action is to scroll the window on arrows. This happen when there are no input element in focus.

In your case you want to prevent default browser behavior but for this you need keydown event because keyup is called after default browser action, so you can't prevent it using keyup:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { // you need keydown
  switch(e.which) {
      case 37: // left
        $(".gallery-nav-left").click();
      break;

      case 39: // right
        $(".gallery-nav-right").click();
      break;

      default: return;
  }
  return false; // or e.preventDefault() - on document it will be the same
});
```